# How to .concat multiple array that has at least one same element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working on this algorithm couple of hour and no luck so far, keep getting into many confusing nested `for` loops and `maximum stack`

Here is the goal,

Given **an input of 2D array**:

```
[[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4]]
```

I want the output to be 2D array again but they group together the element (from input array) that has at least one element is equal to the other element, like connecting the dot.

**So the output be like**

```
[[1,7,1,3,9,7],[2,4]]
```

Why? Because..

- we can connect `[1,7]` with `[1,3]` they have `1` in common,
- we can connect `[1,7]` with `[9,7]` they have `7` in common,
- we can not connect `[2,4]` to anything since we don't have any common `2` or `4` values

So, for example

```
var input = [[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4]];
var output = (function(input) {
   // something i couldn't figure out
   // return = [[1,7,1,3,9,7],[2,4]]
})(input);
// as simple as that
```

Comment: Please integrate your question with your last code

Comment: Replace `// something i couldn't figure out` with `return [[1,7,1,3,9,7],[2,4]];`

Comment: What would be the expected output for the input `[[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4],[4,9]]`? `[[1, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7], [2, 4, 4, 9]]` or `[[1, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 2, 4, 4, 9]]`? How about `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]`? Would that give us `[[1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5]]`?

Comment: the key is group all that are connected, like connecting dot or path, if input `[[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4],[4,9]]` then output should be `[[1, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 2, 4, 4, 9]]` not the other, if input is `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]` then should be `[[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to create new array, and in each iteration check accumulator value to see if some sub-array contains some element from current array using `findIndex` and `some` methods.

```js
const data = [[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4]];
const data2 = [[50], [1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[11,12],[22, 13], [40, 100], [11, 40], [50, 13], [50, 13, 100]]

const connect = (input, repeat = true) => {
  return input.reduce(function(r, e, i, arr) {
    if (!r.length) r.push(e);
    else {
      let index = r.findIndex(a => a.some(el => e.includes(el)));
      index != -1 ? r[index].push(...e) : r.push(e)
    }
    if (repeat) r = connect(r, false)
    return r;
  }, [])
}


let result = connect(data)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))

let result2 = connect(data2)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result2))
```

Comment: try this input `[[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4],[4,9]]` the output is not expected, your code would output `[[1, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 4, 9], [2, 4]]`, not as expected, which is should be `[[1, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 4, 9, 2, 4]]` or `[[1, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 2, 4, 4, 9]]`, order of element does not matter here, as long as grouped like connected network or path. I tried using `reduce` `some` even `map` but no luck, got stuck on algorithm, my brain exploded trying to figure out the correct algorithm.

Comment: @xcode  Actually it's not working in this case https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2668/, but if you repeat it in every iteration it seems to work then https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2669/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you encounter many nested for loops and maximum stack errors, it's because your problem would be best solved recursively. It's possible to do this without recursion, but much easier with it.

```
const input=[[1,7],[1,3],[9,7],[2,4]]
const output=(_input)=>{
    const first=_input[0]
    const match=_input.slice(1).findIndex(_sub=>_sub.some(_element=>first.includes(_element)))
    if(match==-1){
        if(_input.length<=2){
            return _input
        }
        return [first,...output(_input.slice(1))]
    }
    const joined=[first.concat(_input[match+1]),..._input.slice(1,match+1),..._input.slice(match+2)]
    return output(joined)
}

console.log(output(input)) //[[1,7,1,3,9,7],[2,4]]
```

I also tested this with xcodes' list in his comment to Nenad.